# Generate EF orderby expression by string

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

I want to generate expression by string parameter,some code like:

```
private Expression<Func<Task, T>> Generate(string orderby)
{
    switch (orderby)
    {
        case "Time":  
            return t => t.Time;
        case "Money":
            return t => t.RewardMoney;
        default:
            return t => t.Id;
    }
}
```

then call it:

```
_context.Items.OrderBy(Generate("Money"));
```

But It can't compile! I change T to object.

```
private Expression<Func<Task, object>> Generate(string orderby)
```

Then It can compile, but It doesn't work.

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/advanced?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Using [reflection](/questions/tagged/reflection) and [expression-trees](/questions/tagged/expression-trees) you can provide the parameters and then call `OrderBy` function, Instead of returning `Expression<Func<Task, T>>` and then calling `OrderBy`.

Note that `OrderBy` is an extension method and has implemented in both `System.Linq.Enumarable` and `System.Linq.Queryable` classes. The first one is for [linq-to-objects](/questions/tagged/linq-to-objects) and the latter is for [linq-to-entities](/questions/tagged/linq-to-entities). [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) needs the expression tree of the query in order to translate it to SQL commands. So we use the `Queryable` implementation.

It can be done by an extension method(explanations added as comments):

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(
       this IQueryable<TSource> query, string propertyName)
{
    var entityType = typeof(TSource);

    //Create x=>x.PropName
    var propertyInfo = entityType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");
    MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(arg, propertyName);
    var selector = Expression.Lambda(property, new ParameterExpression[] { arg });

    //Get System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy() method.
    var enumarableType = typeof(System.Linq.Queryable);
    var method = enumarableType.GetMethods()
         .Where(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
         .Where(m =>
         {
            var parameters = m.GetParameters().ToList();
            //Put more restriction here to ensure selecting the right overload                
            return parameters.Count == 2;//overload that has 2 parameters
         }).Single();
    //The linq's OrderBy<TSource, TKey> has two generic types, which provided here
    MethodInfo genericMethod = method
         .MakeGenericMethod(entityType, propertyInfo.PropertyType);

    /*Call query.OrderBy(selector), with query and selector: x=> x.PropName
      Note that we pass the selector as Expression to the method and we don't compile it.
      By doing so EF can extract "order by" columns and generate SQL for it.*/
    var newQuery = (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)genericMethod
         .Invoke(genericMethod, new object[] { query, selector });
    return newQuery;
}
```

Now you can call this overload of `OrderBy` like any other overload of it.
For example:

```
var cheapestItems = _context.Items.OrderBy("Money").Take(10).ToList();
```

Which translates to:

```
SELECT TOP (10)  {coulmn names} FROM  [dbo].[Items] AS [Extent1] 
       ORDER BY [Extent1].[Money] ASC
```

This approach can be used to define all overloads of `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` methods to have `string` property selector.

Comment: Excellent extension. I would note that the first parameter should be an `IQueryable<T>`, not an `IEnumerable<T>`. If the OP or any other reader need more, there is a whole library of string-based Linq methods available on NuGet (search for System.Linq.Dynamic) or here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb894665.aspx

Comment: Is there a chance, can we extend order asc or desc? thanks

Comment: @sairfan :  "OrderBy" is ASC by default, by replacing it with "OrderByDescending"  in the where clause you get DESC.

Comment: thanks, have one more question, does it support navigation properties? I'm trying like this `items.OrderBy("Category.Name");` and getting error

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you want more flexibility it's better to go for Dynamic library mentioned in the first comment by KeithS

Comment: how to suppurt `OrderByDescending`? with this code it is not supported.

Comment: @PurTahan You need to make a copy of this extension and change the `m.Name == "OrderBy"` to `m.Name == "OrderByDescending"`. Also, don't forget to change the new method name to `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: FYI - Ditto for .ThenBy() and .ThenByDescending().  Thanks a mil for this answer ... fixed everything for me!!

Answer (score 17):

For those who are looking for a solution in EF Core:

There is a set of functions available in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EF` for dynamic access and query compilation. You can use the `EF.Property` method to sort the queryable by the property names or even shadow properties.
Example:

```cs
bool descending = false;
if (sortOrder.EndsWith("_desc"))
{
    sortOrder = sortOrder.Substring(0, sortOrder.Length - 5);
    descending = true;
}

if (descending)
{
    students = students.OrderByDescending(e => EF.Property<object>(e, sortOrder));
}
else
{
    students = students.OrderBy(e => EF.Property<object>(e, sortOrder));
}
```

Source: [Tutorial: Learn about advanced scenarios - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/advanced?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-dynamic-linq-to-simplify-code)

Answer (score 6):

I referred to the old [System.Linq.Dynamic codebase](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dynamiclinq) in CodePlex and created a quite simple version from the perspective of implementation and invocation. Of course, it's an extension method on `IQueryable<T>`

```
/*
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
*/

public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string orderByExpression)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderByExpression))
        return query;

    string propertyName, orderByMethod;
    string[] strs = orderByExpression.Split(' ');
    propertyName = strs[0];

    if (strs.Length == 1)
        orderByMethod = "OrderBy";
    else
        orderByMethod = strs[1].Equals("DESC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";

    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType);
    MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(pe, propertyName);

    MethodCallExpression orderByCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), orderByMethod, new Type[] { query.ElementType, me.Type }, query.Expression
        , Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(me, pe)));

    return query.Provider.CreateQuery(orderByCall) as IQueryable<T>;
}
```

Here is samples how to use it, tested for Entity Framework Core 3:

```
IQueryable<Person> query = dbContext.People;
query = query.OrderBy("FirstName"); // ORDER BY FirstName
```

```
IQueryable<Person> query = dbContext.People;
query = query.OrderBy("FirstName ASC"); // ORDER BY FirstName
```

```
IQueryable<Person> query = dbContext.People;
query = query.OrderBy("FirstName DESC"); // ORDER BY FirstName DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try converting the `Generate` method in a generic method:

```
private Expression<Func<Task, TResult>> Generate<TResult>(string orderby)
{
     switch (orderby)
     {
        case "Time":  
          return t => t.Time;
        case "Money":
          return t => t.RewardMoney;
        default:
         return t => t.Id;
     }
}
```

So, if you call this method, you need to specify the type of the property that you want to order by:

```
_context.Items.OrderBy(Generate<decimal>("Money"));
```

Now remember that `TResult` can only  be a primitive type or enumeration type.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but  when you pass "Time" as parameter,the call will change: _context.Items.OrderBy(Generate<DataTime>("Time")). This function losts its function?

Answer (score 2):

Use a generic method. Since lambda expressions can only be assigned to strongly typed delegates or expressions, we must use an according temp. Then we can assign this temp to a variable typed as `object`. Finally we can return the result by casting to the result type.

```
public Expression<Func<Task, TResult>> Generate<TResult>(string orderby)
{
    object result;
    switch (orderby) {
        case "Time":
            Expression<Func<Task, DateTime>> temp1 = t => t.Time;
            result = temp1;
            break;
        case "Money":
            Expression<Func<Task, decimal>> temp2 = t => t.RewardMoney;
            result = temp2;
            break;
        default:
            Expression<Func<Task, int>> temp3 = t => t.Id;
            result = temp3;
            break;
    }
    return (Expression<Func<Task, TResult>>)result;
}
```

Comment: @Oliver how to use this

Comment: @ArunPrasadES, `_context.Items.OrderBy(Generate("Money"));`, as the OP wanted to have.

Comment: This answer does not produce `_context.Items.OrderBy(Generate("Money"));` it produces `_context.Items.OrderBy(Generate<decimal>("Money"));` which is bad

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByHelper<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string sortDirection)
    {

        try
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                return source;
            }
            if (propertyName == null)
            {
                return source;
            }

            propertyName = propertyName.First().ToString().ToUpper(new CultureInfo("en-US", false)) + propertyName.Substring(1);
            var type = typeof(T);
            var arg = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");

            var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
            var mExpr = Expression.Property(arg, propertyInfo);
            type = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

            var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), type);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, mExpr, arg);

            var methodName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortDirection) && sortDirection.ToLower(new CultureInfo("en-US", false)) == "desc" ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
            var orderedSource = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(
                method => method.Name == methodName
                        && method.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                        && method.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2
                        && method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), type)
                .Invoke(null, new object[] { source, lambda });

            return (IQueryable<T>)orderedSource;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return source;
        }
    }
```