# Expression of type 'System.Int64' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection, expression-trees

I am trying to create an expression of the following form:

```
e => e.CreationDate;
```

`CreationDate` is of type `long`, however I want the expression to return an `object` instead.

I want to use `object` as a return type because the expression is built dynamically at runtime based on a query paramater. The query parameter specifies the property to access in the expression, such as:

```
> entities?order=creationDate
> entities?order=score
```

As you can see, I can order by different properties with different types, so a return type `object` would allow me to build the expression as generic as possible.

The problem is that when I try to create the expression:

```
ParameterExpression entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity), "e");
Expression propertyAccess = Expression.Property(entityParameter, property);
Expression<Func<Entity, object>> result = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, object>>(propertyAccess, entityParameter);
```

I get the following exception:

> Expression of type 'System.Int64' cannot be used for return type
>   'System.Object'

It is strange, because as far as I know, all types extend from `object` (It seems polymorphism is not yet supported by expression trees).

Nevertheless, I searched on the web and stumbled with this similar question:

[Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200209/expression-of-type-system-int32-cannot-be-used-for-return-type-system-object)

Following [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s answer, I modified my last line to:

```
Expression<Func<Entity, object>> result = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, object>>(Expression.Convert(propertyAccess, typeof(object)), entityParameter);
```

This works fine, but it doesn't generate the expression I want. Instead, it generates something like this:

```
e => Convert(e.CreationDate)
```

I cannot use this solution, because later in the program an exception is thrown if the expression body is not a `MemberExpression` (i.e., a member access operation)

I kept searching on the Internet for a satisfying answer, but couldn't find any.

How can I achieve `e => e.CreationDate` where return type is `object`?

Comment: Do you need to construct an `Expression<Func<Entity, object>>`? You could create a non-generic `LambdaExpression` and construct a `Func<Entity, long>` instead.

Comment: @Lee I want to use the same helper method to build any `MemberExpression`, this means that sometimes I would be returning a `long` and sometimes a `string`. If I don't do it generic, then I would have to duplicate the same method logic for each return type or implementation

Comment: You can make it `Expression<Func<Entity, TResult>>`, something like `OrderBy` in linq `IQueryable`

Comment: If you want to use this expression for `OrderBy`, there is a better way to do it, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31959568/1847988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you use `result` you could create it dynamically with the delegate type `Func<Entity, long>` and type it as a `LambdaExpression`:

```
ParameterExpression entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity), "e");
Expression propertyAccess = Expression.Property(entityParameter, property);
var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Entity), property.PropertyType);
LambdaExpression result = Expression.Lambda(funcType, propertyAccess, entityParameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, it is not possible. Value types need to be boxed to be seen as objects. The compiler does it for you normally, but if you build code yourself (e.g expression trees), you need to specify it as an explicit conversion, the way you see it in  the found answer. If you cannot have it as a non-generic LambdaExpression, I would handle the convert case additionally where you expect the MemberExpression, or use PropertyInfo, and construct the orderby Expression only in the last moment.