# IQueryable GroupBy Lambda expression fails for primitive types with object key

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, iqueryable

I am in process of creating Lambda Expression for an `IQueryable<TSource>`, following is my extension method code, which I need to call like:

`queryableData.GroupBy<int,Product>("ID")`

`queryableData.GroupBy<string,Product>("Name")`

```
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey,TSource>> GroupBy<TKey,TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable, string propertyName)
    {
        // Access the propertyInfo, using Queryable Element Type (Make it Case insensitive)
        var propInfo = queryable.ElementType.GetProperty(propertyName,BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Access the Collection / Queryable Type
        var collectionType = queryable.ElementType;

        // Creating Group Parameter Expression
        var groupParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(collectionType, "g");

        // Create MemberEXpression with the Property (access the property of a Type)
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(groupParameterExpression, propInfo);

        // Create Lambda Expression
        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource,TKey>>(propertyAccess, groupParameterExpression);

        // Return GroupBy result
        return queryable.GroupBy(lambdaExpression);
    }
```

My aim is to generate `Expression<Func<TSource,object>>` instead of `Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>>`, so that it can be called without providing the Key type, following is code:

```
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<object, TSource>> GroupByObjectKey<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable, string propertyName)
    {
        // Access the propertyInfo, using Queryable Element Type (Make it Case insensitive)
        var propInfo = queryable.ElementType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Access the Collection / Queryable Type
        var collectionType = queryable.ElementType;

        // Creating Group Parameter Expression
        var groupParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(collectionType, "g");

        // Create MemberEXpression with the Property (access the property of a Type)
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(groupParameterExpression, propInfo);

        // Create Lambda Expression
        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(propertyAccess, groupParameterExpression);

        // Return GroupBy result
        return queryable.GroupBy(lambdaExpression);
    }
```

Now I able to make it work for string type as follows:

`queryableData.GroupBy<Product>("Name")`

but it fails on following call for integer type with exception as stated underneath:

`queryableData.GroupBy<Product>("Id")`

```
Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'
```

This is a clear case of Type conversion, but I am surprised that why a type would refuse to be converted to Object base class, what could be the rationale, any pointer / suggestion

Comment: would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32146571/1132334) apply here?
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200247/1132334) of course

Comment: Second one does, but I am not sure why is it required for conversion to Object type of all things.It works for reference type but not for primitive types.

Comment: I'd have a go at an answer along the line of "explicit conversion is required here", but cannot say it any better than [Eric Lippert here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object/); *derives from* is not the same as *convertible to*: "The way to correct this myth is to simply replace "derives from" with "is convertible to", and to ignore pointer types: every non-pointer type in C# is *convertible* to object"

Comment: That's one of the gotchas of expressions: value type boxing requires an explicit `Convert` instruction. It's similar to what the compiler does for you when you write code such as `return (object)0;`. Just embrace the fact that value types are different, and run with it.

Comment: Other commenters already mentioned that you need to wrap value type returning expression (`propertyAccess`) with `Expression.Convert`. This will allows you to successfully build you query. But please note that if you are planning to use this in EF6 query, you'll get simply runtime exception *Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.*. In general variance doesn't work with value types. There is a reason for `GroupBy` having `TKey` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments already pointed out, you need to add a conversion to `object`:

```
var convertToObject = Expression.Convert(propertyAccess, typeof(object));

var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(convertToObject, groupParameterExpression);
```

Comment: thanks though I figured out the solution, once I understood the requirement related to Type Conversion