# How to sorting dynamic in lambda entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting, lambda, sql-order-by

I want to sort dynamic in lambda entity framework.I founded it more time, but seem not work.

```
////string column_name // the name of column in table   <<< don't care this, I finished
////string sort_order  // ASC or DESC    <<< don't care this, I finished

using (var db = new ABCEntities())
{
    // get dynamic type of column name , but i can not 
    // ???????????
    var columnExp = typeof(LOCATION).GetProperty(column_name);

    IEnumerable<LOCATION> query = db.LOCATIONs;
    if(sort_order = "ASC")
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(columnExp).Tolist();  
    }
    else
        query = query.OrderByDescending(columnExp).Tolist();    
}
```

I try with follow

```
query = db.LOCATIONs.OrderByDescending(q => q.GetType().GetProperty(column_name).GetValue(q, null)).ToList();
```

But get error at

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
```

Can you tell me some mistake or wrong and how to fix it ? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955025/generate-ef-orderby-expression-by-string

Comment: I try it , but it's not work.

Comment: @BrianCrist Please be more specific. *What* doesn't work? I think you should simply do `OrderBy(column_name)`, assuming that you're using Dynamic LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about use [Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/) ?
It can generate query from string.

```
using (var db = new ABCEntities()){
  var columnExp = "columnName";
  var query = db.LOCATIONs;
  if(sort_order = "ASC")
  {
      query = query.OrderBy(columnExp).Tolist();  
  }
  else
  {
      query = query.OrderByDescending(columnExp).Tolist();
  }
}
```

Comment: using Dynamic Linq, and then modify your code like above.
or paste more of your code?

Comment: Dear kcwu, the answer of you is helpfull, beside , I founded a way this
`var propertyInfo = typeof(LOCATION).GetProperty(columnName); query = db.LOCATIONs.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).ToList();`   . Thank you