# How to order by a dynamic column name in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dynamic-linq

I am trying to get following code working , This was working fine for SQL Server, but since I changed to use MySQL, it is not working.

```
  records.Content = db.areas
                         .Where(x =>   x.Name.Contains(filter)))
                         .OrderBy("dated desc") 
                         .ToList();
```

I get the error:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
> LoaderExceptions property for more information.

```
string colName = "datedD" ;
```

How to order by depending on colName variable?

Comment: I guess by "string version" you mean the so called "Dynamic LINQ" (or System.Linq.Dynamic). Please add `dynamic-linq` tag and update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Kas Can you please check my answer as it seems better method for this question ;D

Comment: try this library [Entity Framework Plus Library - Linq-Dynamic](https://entityframework-plus.net/linq-dynamic). you can also check my answer

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41244/861716

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
string filterString = "dated";
bool isAscSorting = false;

Func<dynamic, dynamic> orderingFunction = i =>
                                filterString == "dated" ? i.dated :
                                filterString == "something" ? i.columnx : "";

records.Content = (isAscSorting) ?
                      db.areas
                         .Where(x =>   x.Name.Contains(filter)))
                         .OrderBy(orderingFunction) 
                         .ToList()
                   :
                        db.areas
                         .Where(x =>   x.Name.Contains(filter)))
                         .OrderByDescending(orderingFunction) 
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Is it possible to stop duplication of this code ?
 
 db.areas
                         .Where(x =>   x.Name.Contains(filter)))

Comment: You cant on this answer But You can use dynamic linq It is complex

Comment: @Kas you can put result of `db.areas.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(filter)))` into local variable `var query = ...` and then use `query = (isAscSorting) ? query.OrderBy(...) : query.OrderByDescending(...)`

Answer (score 66):

In .Net Core, we can use the `EF.Property` method to specify the name of the property as a string:

```
string sortColumn = "Price";

//IQueryable<Product> q = from p in myDbContext.Products select p;
q = q.OrderBy(p => EF.Property<object>(p, sortColumn));
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: if you are not using .Net Core look at @Taher Rahgooy answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955025/generate-ef-orderby-expression-by-string)

Comment: it reduced my whole page query to single line. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I used the mix of 2 answers by @NEER and @S.Serpooshan to aviod LINQ queries

```
IQueryable<area> filteredItems = db.areas.Where(x =>   x.Name.Contains(filter)));
IQueryable<area> orderedItems;
if (IsAscending)
{
    orderedItems = filteredItems.OrderBy(item => typeof(area).GetProperty(colName).GetValue(item).ToString());
}
else
{
    orderedItems = filteredItems.OrderByDescending(item => typeof(area).GetProperty(colName).GetValue(item).ToString());
}
```

The bad thing is - my code is comparing items as strings. I had no time to make it more "type-friendly", but I'm pretty sure it is possible.

Comment: THIS is the Correct answer. also Item => Item.GetType() can be use instead of item => typeof(area)

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic ordering most convenient way I found:

```
string propertyNameForOrdering = "UserName";

var list = context.Customers.OrderByDescendingDynamic(x => "x." + propertyNameForOrdering).ToList(); // DESC

var list = context.Customers.OrderByDynamic(x => "x." + propertyNameForOrdering).ToList(); // ASC
```

[Entity Framework Plus Library - Linq-Dynamic](https://entityframework-plus.net/linq-dynamic)

That feature is free even for commercial use.

Comment: Are you sure it's still free and will remain so? Despite the name, that's not related to the EF team and the company behind it has a habit of picking up abandoned projects and dual-licensing them. Or creating "documentation" sites for other people's projects that promote their own unrelated libraries, like they did with Dapper

Comment: For example, when did "BulkInsert" become a *paid* extension?