# Finding a property name within a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection

I have a coding problem to solve, I kind of know the path I should be following, but there is still something missing. I got a mission to change a code to make it more generic and reduce the redundance.

The whole class is given below. It seems a bit dummy, the question is the redundance itself.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestRedundance
{
    public class EntityRedundance
    {
        public class Entity
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
        }

        private void AddSorting(IQueryable<Entity> query, List<string> sortingColumns, bool orderDescending)
        {

            if (!sortingColumns.Any())
            {
                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
                return;
            }

            foreach (var column in sortingColumns)
            {

                switch (column)
                {

                    case "Name":
                        query = orderDescending ? query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name) : query.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
                        break;
                    case "Description":
                        query = orderDescending ? query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Description) : query.OrderBy(x => x.Description);
                        break;
                    case "ValidFrom":
                        query = orderDescending ? query.OrderByDescending(x => x.ValidFrom) : query.OrderBy(x => x.ValidFrom);
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I understood, the redundance is on repeting the same exact code in each switch case condition, changing only the column to be sorted by.

My intention was to change it to a single line, comparing the property name of my entity with the column name, using Reflection, and then replacing the switch-case block for this single line. But the lambda expression does not allow me to do that. Something like the line below, which is commented because it's sintax is wrong.

```
//query = orderDescending ? query.OrderByDescending(x => 
//x.GetType().GetProperties() : query.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Many thanks.

Comment: Might want to check out this post: [how-to-order-by-a-dynamic-column-name-in-entityframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055150/how-to-order-by-a-dynamic-column-name-in-entityframework)

Comment: Your lambdas are just `Func<Entity, T> where T : [string | DateTime]`. You could write a selector for them if nothing else.

Comment: Note that your code is incorrect - if you use multiple `OrderBy` chained, then the last one is the only sort applied. You must use `ThenBy` if you expect to chain sorting in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. First, preserving strong typing while dynamically adding columns to sort by requires hiding the column selection lambda inside the method so that you have a consistent signature, regardless of the type of the column. Second, LINQ sorting requires `OrderBy` to be followed by `ThenBy` to chain sorts, which means you have another type issue as `ThenBy` expects an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` so assigning to `query` won't work. Thirdly, assigning to `query` doesn't change anything after the method returns, since that is a parameter to the `AddSorting` method and the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` methods return new objects that will be lost when the method returns.

So to fix these issues, first we can create some helper dictionaries to map a `bool` (`orderDescending`) to a particular sorting method for each type of column, one for `OrderBy` and one for `ThenBy`:

```
static Dictionary<bool, Func<IQueryable<Entity>, Expression<Func<Entity, string>>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>>> stringOrderByDirMap = new() {
    { false, Queryable.OrderBy<Entity, string> },
    { true, Queryable.OrderByDescending<Entity, string> },
};

static Dictionary<bool, Func<IOrderedQueryable<Entity>, Expression<Func<Entity, string>>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>>> stringThenByDirMap = new() {
    { false, Queryable.ThenBy<Entity, string> },
    { true, Queryable.ThenByDescending<Entity, string> },
};

static Dictionary<bool, Func<IQueryable<Entity>, Expression<Func<Entity, DateTime>>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>>> dateTimeOrderByDirMap = new() {
    { false, Queryable.OrderBy<Entity, DateTime> },
    { true, Queryable.OrderByDescending<Entity, DateTime> },
};

static Dictionary<bool, Func<IOrderedQueryable<Entity>, Expression<Func<Entity, DateTime>>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>>> dateTimeThenByDirMap = new() {
    { false, Queryable.ThenBy<Entity, DateTime> },
    { true, Queryable.ThenByDescending<Entity, DateTime> },
};
```

Using these, you can create a couple of dictionaries (one for `OrderBy` and one for `ThenBy`) which map column names to a lambda function that takes a `bool` and returns a lambda that maps a `IQueryable<T>` or `IOrderedQueryable<T>` to an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` for the appropriate column:

```
static Dictionary<string, Func<bool, Func<IQueryable<Entity>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>>>> firstSort = new() {
    { "Name", desc => q => stringOrderByDirMap[desc](q, e => e.Name) },
    { "Description", desc => q => stringOrderByDirMap[desc](q, e => e.Description) },
    { "ValidFrom", desc => q => dateTimeOrderByDirMap[desc](q, e => e.ValidFrom) },
};

static Dictionary<string, Func<bool, Func<IOrderedQueryable<Entity>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>>>> thenSort = new() {
    { "Name", desc => q => stringThenByDirMap[desc](q, e => e.Name) },
    { "Description", desc => q => stringThenByDirMap[desc](q, e => e.Description) },
    { "ValidFrom", desc => q => dateTimeThenByDirMap[desc](q, e => e.ValidFrom) },
};
```

With all of these setup, your `AddSorting` method becomes

```
private IQueryable<Entity> AddSorting(IQueryable<Entity> query, List<string> sortingColumns, bool orderDescending) {
    if (!sortingColumns.Any())
        return query.OrderBy(x => x.Name);

    IOrderedQueryable<Entity> sortedQuery = null;

    foreach (var column in sortingColumns) {
        if (sortedQuery == null)
            sortedQuery = firstSort[column](orderDescending)(query);
        else
            sortedQuery = thenSort[column](orderDescending)(sortedQuery);
    }
    
    return sortedQuery;
}
```

Given your example of only three columns, using Reflection to build `Expression` trees seems like overkill, however, you could populate the `firstSort` and `thenSort` dictionaries using Reflection from a type and list of columns instead of coding their initial values. You would need to code appropriate `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` maps for each possible column type.