# Expressions with dynamic return types (dynamic keyword)

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-expressions

My ultimate goal here is to make a generic version of `IQueryable<T>.OrderBy()` that takes a string parameter and an optional sort direction.  Something like these:

```
return myList.OrderBy("Property1");
return myList.Orderby("Property1", SortOrder.Descending);
```

(The use case would be a website passing in a field the list would sort by.)

To that end, I've been trying to come up with a way of creating the following expression:

```
obj => obj.PropertyName
```

I've found a few places in StackOverflow that could help me, and they've gotten me quite close ([this one in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31959568/112829)).  Butt it doesn't quite get me all the way there.  Specifically I keep getting the dreaded 
*Expression of type 'System.Int64' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'* for value types.  I thought I could get away with return `dynamic` here, but that seems to have fallen over.  I could do a `Convert`, but that seems like it should be unnecessary.

My code for generating the property selector is as follows:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> GeneratePropertySelector<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var objectType = typeof(T);
    var property = objectType.GetProperty(propertyName);

    ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(objectType, "obj");
    MemberExpression propertyExpression = Expression.Property(arg, propertyName);

    // Here is the line that dies
    var selectorExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, dynamic>>(propertyExpression, new ParameterExpression[] { arg });

    return selectorExpression;
}
```

And then usage inside the extension method implementation would be:

```
var ordered = myList.OrderBy(GeneratePropertySelector("Property1"));
```

For a `string` property, this works fine; for an `int` property, error.

Does anyone know how to get around this?  I would have thought that `dynamic` would have helped here, but I'm at a loss.  And given my use case, I'm trying to avoid something like this:

```
return myList.Orderby<int>("MyIntProperty");
```

Comment: sounds like you really want this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/23354

Comment: Hmm.  That may have something in there I can work with.  The main answer seems to date from 2008, but there are some newer things in there that I might be able to use.  I'll try it out tonight or tomorrow and get back to you with how it goes.

Comment: @MarcGravell Whoops, I forgot to respond to this.  Sorry!  That link gave me what I needed to fix the problem.  Thank you!