# Linq to SQL OrderBy based on selectedvalue from DropDownList

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a list of 10 articles which gets displayed with the following Linq to SQL query in the page load event:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            MyDataClassesDataContext db = new MyDataClassesDataContext();

            var pressRelease = from pr in db.PressReleases
                orderby pr.DatePublished ascending 
                where pr.Published == true
                select pr;

            int i = 0;

            foreach (var release in pressRelease)
            {
                Literal literal = new Literal();
                literal.Text = "<div class='row no-gutters pb-5'><div class='col-12'><h2>" +
                               release.Title + "</h2>" + Server.HtmlDecode(release.Content) + "</h2>" +
                               "<a href='Press-Release.aspx?id=" + release.Id +
                               "'><b>Read article...</b></a></div></div>";
                pnlPressReleaases.Controls.Add(literal);
            }
        }
```

On my web page, I have a dropdownlist with the following values and the autopostback set to true.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPressSortBy" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPressSortBy_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="pr.DatePublished descending">Date Published Desc</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="pr.DatePublished ascending">Date Published Asc</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="pr.Title ascending">Alphabetical</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Once I change the value of the dropdownlist, the data returned has no orderby on the corresponding select statement.  Here is my code for the OnSelectIndexChanged event:

```
protected void ddlPressSortBy_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDataClassesDataContext db = new MyDataClassesDataContext();

        var pressRelease = from pr in db.PressReleases
            orderby ddlPressSortBy.SelectedValue
            where pr.Published == true
            select pr;


        foreach (var release in pressRelease)
        {
            Literal literal = new Literal();
            literal.Text = "<div class='row no-gutters pb-5'><div class='col-12'><h2>" +
                           release.Title + "</h2>" + Server.HtmlDecode(release.Content) + "</h2>" + "<a href='Press-Release.aspx?id=" + release.Id + "'><b>Read article...</b></a></div></div>";
            pnlPressReleaases.Controls.Add(literal);
        }
    }
```

I'm a little unsure why it is not firing with the orderby.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955025/generate-ef-orderby-expression-by-string

Comment: what are the values in `ddlPressSortBy` are there a lot or only 1 or 2 -- it is easier if it is just a few values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do sorting this way:

```
var pressRelease = from pr in db.PressReleases
        orderby ddlPressSortBy.SelectedValue
        where pr.Published == true
        select pr;
```

because resulting query would be something like (suppose you selected the first item):

```
SELECT * FROM PressReleases
WHERE Published = 1
ORDER BY 'pr.DatePublished descending'
```

`ORDER BY` clause would be by a fixed value, resulting in default sorting.

Linq OrderBy takes an `Expression<Func<T, object>>`, that would be something like `pr => pr.DatePublishing`, if you are using Fluent syntax. Query syntax just hides that in pretty form, but it how it works.

Accordingly to [this article](https://ronniediaz.com/2011/05/24/orderby-string-in-linq-c-net-dynamic-sorting-of-anonymous-types/), you could create an extension method for IQueryable that allows you to sort using property names:

```
public static class extensionmethods
{
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string SortField, bool Ascending)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
        string method = Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
        Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
        return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
    }
}
```

and then use it in your code like this:

```
var sortingInfo = ddlPressSortBy.SelectedValue.Split(' ');
var sortingProperty = sortingInfo[0];
var descending = sortingInfo[1] == "descending";

var pressRelease = from pr in db.PressReleases
        where pr.Published == true
        select pr;
pressRelease = pressRelease.OrderByField(sortingProperty, descending);
// rest of code
```